# Mingw Compiler is not detected in scilab

Tags: gcc, windows-10, mingw, scilab

I have downloaded Scilab 6.1.1 and I'm trying to install the Mingw compiler that it's on the ATOMS section, specifically in Windows Tools, but the compiler is not detected and I don't know why.

I installed the compiler (the window of the installation says everything was correctly installed) and when I re-open scilab, it says

```
Mingw Compiler support for Scilab
    Load macros
WARNING: MinGW Compiler not detected.
    Load help
```

also I run the code

```
haveacompiler
```

but it returns as

> haveacompiler
> ans  =  F

I unistall everything, and tried everything from the top and it's the same. I don't know what to change or do because is my first time dealing with this kind of programs, and I don't want to do something that might affect my laptop.

[pic of my scilab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwEr4.png)

p.s. I have Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Please open a command window (type `cmd` in the search bar) and give the result of the command `echo %%EQ_LIBRARY_PATH%%`. Please note that you are supposed to exit then reopen your Windows session after installing the MinGW gcc package.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this scilab-compiler error and after some hacks i solved it. What to do:

1. get the value of windows-variable %%EQ_LIBRARY_PATH%%
2. Copy mingw-gcc into the folder denoted by %%EQ_LIBRARY_PATH%%
3. Deinstall Scilab completely and reinstall it or
   install a new version.
4. Open scilab and install atoms(mingw)
5. Close scilab
6. Clear windows folder protection
7. Reopen scilab,perhaps on console
   Now scilab compiles some libs needed to work with mingw
   and xcos. On console one can see libs-compile
   perhaps an easier way is possible. but i dont know it.
   I like folder protection, so I reactivated it.
   Good luck